# AMD CPU Overheats with nested virtualization

Tags: windows-8, cpu, 64-bit, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I am currently trying to do nested virtualization using the AMD FX 6100 processor. Everytime I try to install a VM in hyper-v the CPU overheats and the system shuts down.

Here are the specs:

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- AMD FX 6100
- SVM is ON aka AMD-V
- Motherboard: M5A97R2
- Memory: 32GB
- VMware Workstation 10
- Server 2012 R2 with Hyper-V installed

VMX file settings per Hyper-V VM:

- hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = “FALSE”
- mce.enable = “TRUE”
- vhu.enable = “TRUE”

System information:

- Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions Yes
- Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions    Yes
- Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware Yes
- Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection  Yes

Comment: Hyper V or not, it should not shut down. What are your temps ? do a burn test with Intel XTU or prime95. If the cpu still overheats, then the problem is not related to virtualization functions..

Comment: @Neil the CPU goes up to 80 degrees and then the machine shutsdown. When there are no nested vms running, all is good.

Comment: 80 Degrees is *a lot*. it idles @ how much ?

Comment: @Neil it idles at 30-35 degrees

Comment: Have you checked event logs for reason.

Comment: It sounds like you should resolve the CPU overheating problem.  Are you using stock or aftermarket cooling?  If you are using stock, time to upgrade, try aftermarket air cooling before you switch to liquid cooling for simplicity.

Comment: @Ramhound I upgraded to after market cooling and that worked!